# Sonar Let Anonymous user see the reports

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have setup code coverage and created dashboards to show reports using SonarQube.

I tries many options but could not publish dashboard to anonymous user.

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the 'Anyone' group from the 'Browse' permission of your project.
See http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Authorization for details.